# Error on ddev start: The docker version currently installed does not meet ddev's requirements: 17.6.2-ce is less than 18.06.0-ce

Tags: docker, version, ddev

docker --version shows:

```
Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a
```

ddev version

```
cli     v1.1.1                    
web     drud/ddev-webserver:v1.1.0
db      drud/ddev-dbserver:v1.1.0 
dba     drud/phpmyadmin:v1.1.0    
router  drud/ddev-router:v1.1.0   
commit  v1.1.1                    
domain  ddev.local
```

**ddev Documentation says:**
Docker version 18.03 or higher. Linux users make sure you do the post-install steps

ddev start results in an error:
The docker version currently installed does not meet ddev's requirements: 17.6.2-ce is less than 18.06.0-ce

Where does that mismatch come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fault!

Did an install via snap of docker first under Ubuntu 16.04 and forgot to remove it.

```
vagrant@drupalvm:/etc$ snap list
Name      Version     Rev   Tracking  Publisher   Notes
core      16-2.34.3   5145  stable    canonical   core
docker    17.06.2-ce  179   stable    docker-inc  -
phpstorm  2018.2.2    49    stable    jetbrains   classic
```

So on startup docker 17.06 was started. 
After doing a restart of the docker service it was starting the correct version.
Finnally I removed the snap installed one.

Comment: Thanks for the followup! I thought there had to be another docker in there somewhere :)